# Using Javascript to display an input (A number) from a user to a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked at the other questions that are asking similar things to this question however when I attempted to create my own I can't get it to work properly and i dont understand why. It's only very basic before I introduce it into a more complex system I just wanted to try and get the functionality done.

This is my HTML;

```
<div id="test2">
    Please enter a number: <input type="number" id="RValue1">
    <button id="test" onclick="R1Value()">Change Value</button>
</div>

<div id="ShowR1"></div>
```

And this is the JavaScript;

```
function R1Value() {
    var t = document.getElementById("RValue1");
    var div = document.getElementById('ShowR1');
    div.innerHTML = t.value;    
}
```

I have made this fiddle to save time and so you can have a look at it,

http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/52/

I can't see why this doesn't seem to work so if anyone can see why I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You defined `R1Value` function inside `window.onload` function, hence making it local variable and not accessible globally. Fixed demo http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/53/

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/54/ Notice I changed it to run from the `head` and not `onload`, where it's inaccessible to global scope.

Comment: @dfsq Wow I'm sorry that I missed that i feel very foolish bothering for that, thank you for correcting this for me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the button:

Try out this: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/56/

Type in the text, then you can just call the, `".value"`, method to get its text. Then everything else works the way you've written it.

Comment: I think they beat you at the comments

Comment: i think they did, ah well

Comment: I did find this in another questions which is where i based my answer off unfortunately I need it to be a button that triggers it not just when they exit the field, but thank you for your suggestion!